# React Native Navigation Component Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using [react navigation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation) as per the docs but trying to make my app a bit more modular. I placed the result of `createStackNavigator` into a separate component..

**Navigator.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Home from './views/Home.js';
import TestComponent from './views/TestComponent.js';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Test: {screen: TestComponent}
});

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

..and importing this component into my App.js

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import Header from './Header.js';
import Navigator from './Navigator.js';
import FooterMenu from './FooterMenu.js';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <Header />
        <Navigator />
        <FooterMenu />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My **index.js** is as follows:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './components/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Im finding that my `<Header/>` and `<FooterMenu/>` components are rendering but the `<Navigator/>` component is not.

I found that if I replace the top-level `<View>` component with a React fragment, it *does* render.

```
render() {

return (
  <>
    <Header />
    <Navigator />
    <FooterMenu />
  </>
);
}
```

Although this **syntax** breaks my editor's (sublime) **syntax** highlighting. Though if I change the fragment to `<React.Fragment>` **React native** throws an exception.

My questions are:

1. Why does `<Navigator/>` not render if I wrap it in a `<View>` component?
2. Why do I get an error if I use `<React.Fragment>`?

Comment: There is no render method in your Navigator.js then what it will render ?

Comment: that's a good point. but it does manage to render if the top level component is a fragment. how come?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create your own Navigator, here's how.

It is possible to take an existing Navigator and extend its behavior, using the following approach:

```js
const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ ... });

class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = MyStack.router;
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return <MyStack navigation={navigation} />;
  }
}
```

Now it is possible to render additional things, observe the navigation prop, and override behavior of the router:

```js
const MyStack = createStackNavigator({ ... });

class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = {
    ...MyStack.router,
    getStateForAction: (action, lastState) => {
      // check for custom actions and return a different navigation state.
      return MyStack.router.getStateForAction(action, lastState);
    },
  };
  componentDidUpdate(lastProps) {
    // Navigation state has changed from lastProps.navigation.state to this.props.navigation.state
  }
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <Header />
        <MyStack navigation={navigation} />
        <FooterMenu />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[If you want to know more about this,](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html)

Comment: this was very helpful! thank you for the answer and link to docs

Comment: I am still finding that the component is not rendering. when I `export default CustomNavigator` I get saying `in react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly` but when I `export default createAppContainer(CustomNavigator);` the component doesnt render again

Comment: Have you looked through the documents I linked to? You can use `createNavigator`

Comment: yes, but its not clear what `NavigationView, router, navigationConfig` are to be passed to createNavigator

Comment: refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html OR https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-routers.html

Comment: navigationConfig  : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html